You can always expect me to tell you what I have done/did. - differences in meaning?
Example 1

You can always expect me to tell you what I did.

Example 2

You can always expect me to tell you what I have done.

Does Example 1 refer to a specific past time or it can mean the same thing as Example 2?
Example 2 refers to a time in a general sense in my opinion.

"What I have done" gives a sense of a process finishing. "I'll tell you what I have done. Yesterday, I worked all day, moving 2,500 pounds of barley."
"What I did" gives a slight sense of a non-sustained decision or shorter event. "The lights went out. What I did was pour water on the power line."

"You can always expect me to tell you what I did." This reads like:

"You can always expect me to tell you which actions I have completed."

"You can always expect me to tell you what I have done." This reads like:

"You can always expect me to tell you what I have accomplished." (Slightly more results oriented.)
However, this is very subtle. They are interchangeable. Saying "what I did over my career is. . ." or "what I have done to break the computer again is. . ." both sound natural.
In general, "what I did" sounds more natural for most scenarios.

OP's query is on the differences between the two sentences:


You can always expect me to tell you what I did.
You can always expect me to tell you what I have done.


Both sentences aim to establish trust and confidence, but in different contexts and with varying emphasis.
Differences
1. Purpose:.
Sentence 1 :
Reassure about pasr actions  in personal relationships.
Sentence 2:
Promise transparency, accountability, and ongoing communication in  professional/ formal contexts.
2. Tense used:
Sentence 1:
Simple Past shows completed tasks in the past.
Sentence 2:
Present Perfect shows the relationship between the past and the present.
3. Time Frame:.
Sentence 1:
Implied past completion.
Sentence 2:
No specific time frame required (focus on present relevance).
4. Relevance:.
Sentence 1:
Past deeds without a clear relationship to the present.
Sentence 2:
Past actions with present relevance
5. Typical context:
Sentence 1:
Personal relationships (spouse, close friends, etc.).
Sentence 2:
Professional/ formal relationships (e.g., employee-manager, business partners), where transparency and trust need to be established or maintained.
